# How to parse / split and print the URL?

Tags: java, url-parsing

Can someone help with url parsing splitting?

I have  urls like below -

Actual - `https://www.facebook.com/group.php/gid=12345`
Expecting  - `facebook /group.php/gid=12345`

Actual - `https://www.Test.this.domain/testPath/`
Expecting - `https wwwtestthisdomain testpath`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: How does it work ? second one has https and www in result but first one only has "facebook"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.net.URI` like following:

```java
    URI uri = URI.create("https://www.facebook.com/group.php/gid=12345");
    System.out.println(
        uri.getPath() // prints: /group.php/gid=12345
    );
    System.out.println(
        uri.getHost() // www.facebook.com
    );
```